# BASH Script running as root, tidy way to group commands run as another user?

Tags: bash, root, su

I'm aware that i can run each command as a different user with:

```
su -s /bin/bash "command" - user
```

But there's several commands to run and i was looking for a neater way to do it than putting su on every line.

How can i say 'all commands from here run as userX' and then 'stop running commands as userX' (and continue running the rest of the script as root)?

Thanks.

Here's the block i'd like to run as a different user (updated from answer given by @Jetchisel):

```
#!/bin/bash
export BORG_PASSPHRASE="SUPERSECRETPASSWORD"

su - backup-user -s /bin/bash -c '
echo "$USER $(date +%F)" |& tee /pathto/_logs/test.log
borg info               \
    /pathto/repo          \
    |& tee -a /pathto/_logs/test.log
'
info_exit=$?{PIPESTATUS[0]}

if [ ${info_exit} = "0" ]; then
echo ">> test-SUCCESS <<"
elif [ ${info_exit} = "1" ]; then
echo ">> test WARNINGS <<"
else
echo ">> test FAILED <<"
fi
```

The above works but for two things:

1. I can't seem to pass the environment variable that Borg normally picks up automatically: $BORG_PASSPHRASE. Is this maybe a permissions issue between users?
2. It doesn't seem to pass the info=exit correctly. For a test i removed Borg entirely retained echo but misspelled it 'ech' which fails. But the script reports as success regardless.

Comment: Exporting the password into a environment variable is not a good idea. A password shouldn't be in a script or passed to an environment variable.

Comment: I understand, but this is a single-user device that is encrypted.

Comment: Then why run commands as another user? And how does it benefit you in any way to put the user's password in a script? When running the script as root, you don't need the user's password, therefore you can avoid the horrible practice of putting a password in a script.

Comment: The reason it doesn't run as root is because the file-set it's working on isn't owned by root. The files are put there over ssh as a different user. It still needs the password because it's a backup-set which is password encrypted and runs to a schedule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `-c` flag

```
 OPTIONS
       -c, --command=command
            Pass command to the shell with the -c option.
```

Something like

```
su - "$user" -s /bin/bash -c 'command1;command1;command3;.....'
```

Or use new lines instead of `;` to separate the commands.

```
su - "$user" -s /bin/bash -c '
  command1
  command2
  command3
  ...
'
```

Just need to take care of the quoting if you need to quote the commands with single quotes.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, i think it's because the commands are not one-liners and reasonably complex, one portion checks if a path is available before continuing or exiting, another part has 3 separately run Borg backup commands. Looking in the editor, the text colouring didn't seem right if the syntax was correct. I've updated the post to hopefully be more useful. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Derek It should work. The complexity of the commands don't matter at all, but you may want to `export` your `BORG_REPO` and `LOGFILE` variables to be able to access them inside the `bash -c` script.

Comment: You're right it does work - i did have variables in the full script, but there were some missing in my test script. Thanks both @Kusalananda and Jetchisel. I've updated the original question because while it works for the ultra-basic, i'm still having trouble with a couple of things that seem to be as a result of 'blocking' the commands inside the single quotes.

Comment: Exporting the password into a environment variable is not a good idea. A password shouldn't be in a script or passed to an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions in your bash script, along with *typeset* to easily accomplish that;

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

function1 () {
  echo "this is function1"
 }
function2 () {
  echo "this is function2"
}

su -c "$(typeset -f function1); function1" user1
su -c "$(typeset -f function2); function2" user2


exit 0
```

Put whatever commands you wish to run inside the function and the respective user will run all of those commands.

> ***NOTE:*** you will run the script as root to easily avoid any password issues

```bsh
sudo su -c ./script.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

Eh. I'm new to stackexchange. Otherwise this would be a comment instead of an answer. I don't have the rep to comment. So guys. Take it easy on me! I recommend that you use ssh instead of su. And I recommend having root and backup-user share a common primary UNIX group.

1. With ssh the backup-user password can change and your script will still work.
2. If you use a shared group - later - after your proof-of-concept analysis - you can migrate to a solution where an account other than root can own and execute the script. This has the advantage of making it so you don't have to share the root password.
3. You can pass environment variables in the ssh command... Like: ssh bla@blah "export BORG_PASSPHRASE=\"SUPERSECRETPASSWORD\"; ./script.sh"

Comment: Exporting the password into a environment variable is not a good idea. A password shouldn't be in a script or passed to an environment variable.

Comment: @Shōgun8 While this is certainly true, please note that this approach was actually the one attempted by the OP, so your comment might be better placed under the originap question ...